# create a custom code completion for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-completion

I am trying to make a plugin for eclipse to add more results in the code completion window. 
In order to do that i need to [get a reference to the Java Editor in order to override the getContentAssistant method of the editor’s SourceViewerConfiguration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F).

So, how can i get that reference?
Thank you

PS. feel free to provide any suggestions or links that can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [javaCompletionProposalComputer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html). The link you gave is not useful, as that is only for people who implement a language editor, but the Java editor already exists.

Comment: Thanks! It seems your link is exactly what i want! I am going to check it as soon as possible!