# Adding custom Eclipse completions like sysout

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried several different searches for this, but couldn't find any that is what I'm trying to get, so sorry if there is a question like this already, but anyways;

I want to add custom completions for Eclipse, exactly the same as when you type `sysout` and hit `Ctrl + Space` and it turns it into `System.out.println();`

but with a custom end result and a custom trigger "word/sentence".

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a custom code completion for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220691/create-a-custom-code-completion-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates. There you can add new ones.

For example I have made new custom completion where I just want to System.Out selected text.

```
System.out.println("${word_selection}:" + ${word_selection});${cursor}
```